# Making \paragraph{} spacing the same as other paragraphs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, acm

I am using the [ACM proceedings template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). I use the `\paragraph{}` command to highlight a few words at the beginning of the paragraph. However, the paragraph spacing is significantly more when I use the `\paragraph` command:

```
A typical paragraph....

Another typical paragraph...  

\paragraph{The paragraph with title} The paragraph with title...
```

[image]

**How can I make the paragraph spacings equal** disregarding whether or not the \paragraph is used?

**I cannot change the .cls file** of the template (because we're not allowed to upload it alongside the document), but need to neutralize the template's spacings within the latex code of the my own article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\paragraph` is (despite the poor name) not related to paragraphs but rather is a section heading, following subsection and subsubsection in the hierarchy. It shares all the heading code for automatic numbering and adding entries to the table of contents, although numbering is by default not used at this heading level in the standard classes.

So if this paragraph is not in a new sub-section and you just want a font change then simply

```
\textit{The paragraph with the title.} Zzzzz
```

Is perhaps the most natural markup.

While it would be possible to redefine  `\paragraph` it is usually strongly advised *not* to redefine or change a journal class layout code as it can complicate (or prevent) inclusion of your document in the journal or proceedings if your definitions conflict with the overall processing of the combined work.

Comment: Thanks specifically for the advice at the end. I ended up using the solution by @Zim, but instead of redefining \paragraph, I simply defined another command for it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this is changing the template, but as it happens in the document and needs no change to `acmart.cls`, maybe the copy editors will accept it. If not, they'll revert to the standard.

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\parindent}%
  {0pt}
  {-\parindent}
  {\ACM@NRadjust{\@parfont\@adddotafter}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[2]

\paragraph{This has a title} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\renewcommand` to give `\paragraph` a new implementation that doesn't contain any paragraph spacing. You can put this in your ACM body or sigconf file.

```
 \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{
     \textit{#1.} 
 }
```

The argument of `\paragraph` (`#1`) will be concatenated with a dot and put in italics. Your paragraph implementation will not modify the normal paragraph spacing anymore.

[image: Regular paragraph spacing by redefining the paragraph command]